# 1970s military SF series where a character worked out in a force-field-resistance tank

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to recall the name or author of a series I read in the 1970s. Cast included a team of characters that were paramilitary and each member had special talents.

Two distinct characteristics I can recall include a needle or flechette gun that was lethal but left almost no entry wound, and a overly-muscled character that worked out in a "tank" that used a force field as the resistance for total body exercises which was tuneable in resistance.

Comment: Is this tank? a real Tank (I can think of several stories (ie: A Boy and His Tank by Leo Frankowski) or is the "tank" just a container that he climbs in occasionally for excersize workout.  In the story I listed above the boy climbs into a holding tank inside the Tank which does function to excersize his body also.  BUT all his companions also ride in similar Tanks so no one had special talents IIFC

Comment: Thanks but that’s not it. It is a tank specifically for exercise. The muscled up guy is part of a team that execute missions, but they are not full military as I recall.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like Steve Perry's [Matador series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Perry_(author)#The_Matador_series), in particular, [Brother Death](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441544762) for the character who uses force field resistance training rather than physical weights. However, the series was written in the mid-1980's through early 1990's, which doesn't match your remembered date.

Apologies if links to Amazon aren't The Thing To Do.

Comment: Oh!  The protagonist of *The Man Who Never Missed* uses (non-lethal) dart guns (spetsdōd).